# Working with lidar points (LAS To Multipoint) in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, lidar, malaysia

Currently I'm working with the LAS format and want to transform from WGS84 to RSO Kertau Malaysia.

I'm using ArcGIS-Las to Multipoint and Data Management Tool-Project and succeeded in the conversion.

However the output gave only 1 default class, as the raw files are already classified into their respective classes (ground, vegetation, buildings, etc.).

Are there any other ways of conversion which at the same time creates the classes?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your LAS is already classified, so you could project it first, then convert to multi-points.

The Projections and Transformations toolbox offers a Raster toolset which includes the ProjectRaster tool.

Or, if the problem is actually with the conversion to multi-point, make sure your input class options are defined. I'm not a LAS expert but knowing ArcGIS tools, I suspect there is something you want to specify to make sure the values wind up in the final results.

Comment: I already tried to tick at input class codes & input return values (return 1-5 and last returns)  as I know the result come up with only 1 default class is because only any returns option is ticked. However the result come up with error due to return and class code.

Comment: @syaz Rather than responding via temporary comments, I think you should **edit** your question to revise it with this clarification.  For some hints on how to attract potential answerers I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353